# finding and plotting second derivative of a signal

Tags: matlab

```
clc  

clear all

x= -2:0.1:4;

y= (3*x.^3)-(26*x)+10;  

y1= diff(y)./diff(x);    

y2= diff(y1)./diff(x);      

plot(x,y,'R')              

hold on                  

plot(x,y1,'G')           

hold on     

plot(x,y2,'B')
```

Is this right way to find second derivative?
It's not finding the second derivative and giving an error that matrix dimensions must agree in line 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have values `y` that correspond to the values `x`. While calculating the approximation to the first derivatives `y1` of `y`, you use finite differences. These kind of finite differences approximate the derivative best at the points inbetween `x`. This means your calculation of the approximation of the second derivative should involve `(x(1:end-1)+x(2:end))/2`:

```
x1 = (x(1:end-1) + x(2:end))/2;

y2 = diff(y1) / diff(x1);
```

Note that these approximations `y2` best approximate the second derivative at the positions `x2 = (x1(1:end-1) + x1(2:end))/2`.

---

All in all your code might look like this:

```
%// Clear command window, delete all variables, close all figures
clc;  
clear all;
close all;

%// Define function
f = @(x) (3*x.^3)-(26*x)+10;

%// Define positions
x = -2:0.1:4;

%// Calculate f(x)                       
y= f(x);  

%// Calculate approximation to first derivative and their positions
x1 = (x(1:end-1) + x(2:end))/2;
y1 = diff(y) ./ diff(x);

%// Calculate approximation to second derivative and their positions
x2 = (x1(1:end-1) + x1(2:end))/2; 
y2 = diff(y1) ./ diff(x1);      

%// Plot
plot(x, y, 'R',...
     x1,y1,'G',...
     x2,y2,'B');              
legend('f','f''', 'f''''');
```

Comment: I assign to `f` an [anonymous function](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). This is very convienient in some cases, but not really necessary here. Instead of defining `f` you could calculate `y` by `y = (3*x.^3)-(26*x)+10;`

Comment: it helped alot...i'll ask more questions in future...thanx